# The textBox for login, for my VB.NET web app, doesn't auto-fill for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer

My TextBox for a login email address does not auto-fill on Internet Explorer 11 for My Visual Basic (2017 Pro) web app.  My IE browser > Tools > Options > .. AutoComplete Settings has all checked.

Chrome auto-fills in same web page perfectly.

Comment: Please post the code for the <form> and <input> tags? I have a hunch.

Comment: Sorry to say but as a user with 3K rep, you asked a very low quality question(reason: It lacks of required infos)